# Getting error 'Failed to resolve System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit' on build

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, codedom

I'm trying to add some old MVC project (.net framework 4.7.2) into xamarin forms.
I'm getting this issue "Failed to resolve System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit".
I can't find any reference to CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit anywhere in MVC code but still, I'm getting this issue while building xamarin.ios. 
Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You could install the package `System.CodeDom` from nuget .

Comment: I did that but its still not working @LucasZhang-MSFT